# Javascript - debugging es6 source maps in Firefox

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, ecmascript-6, systemjs

While Firefox is able to show original es6 source files, it's not able to put any breakpoint. I tried using `debugger` statement on code, but not able to make any sense on where Firefox is breaking. My codebase uses `system.js`.

But in Chrome everything just works. So I am not sure who is the culprit here, Firefox or system.js